# Ingesting Kafka Stream Data from C# Library into Druid

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, druid, confluent-platform

I've been trying to ingest some data from Kafka into Druid for the past few days and until now I fail miserably.

I'm creating some basic data with Confluent's C# library like this:

```
using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                var dr = await p.ProduceAsync("Test", new Message<string, string> { Key = "Random", Value = i.ToString(), Timestamp = new Timestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, TimestampType.CreateTime) });
                Console.WriteLine($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
                p.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            }
```

And this adds the data successful. But when I try to get the data into Druid, nothing happens after Task creation and it tells me, that the data is unparseable.

This is my ingestion spec:

```
    {
  "type": "kafka",
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "Test",
    "parser": {
      "type": "string",
      "parseSpec": {
        "format": "json",
        "timestampSpec": {
          "column": "time",
          "format": "auto"
        },
        "dimensionsSpec": {
          "dimensions": [
            {
              "name": "Random",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "metricsSpec": [],
    "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
      "queryGranularity": {
        "type": "none"
      },
      "rollup": true,
      "intervals": null
    },
    "transformSpec": {
      "filter": null,
      "transforms": []
    }
  },
  "tuningConfig": {
    "type": "kafka",
    "maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,
    "maxBytesInMemory": 0,
    "maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000,
    "maxTotalRows": null,
    "intermediatePersistPeriod": "PT10M",
    "maxPendingPersists": 0,
    "indexSpec": {
      "bitmap": {
        "type": "concise"
      },
      "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
      "metricCompression": "lz4",
      "longEncoding": "longs"
    },
    "buildV9Directly": true,
    "reportParseExceptions": false,
    "handoffConditionTimeout": 0,
    "resetOffsetAutomatically": false,
    "segmentWriteOutMediumFactory": null,
    "workerThreads": null,
    "chatThreads": null,
    "chatRetries": 8,
    "httpTimeout": "PT10S",
    "shutdownTimeout": "PT80S",
    "offsetFetchPeriod": "PT30S",
    "intermediateHandoffPeriod": "P2147483647D",
    "logParseExceptions": false,
    "maxParseExceptions": 2147483647,
    "maxSavedParseExceptions": 0,
    "skipSequenceNumberAvailabilityCheck": false
  },
  "ioConfig": {
    "topic": "Test",
    "replicas": 1,
    "taskCount": 1,
    "taskDuration": "PT600S",
    "consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
    },
    "pollTimeout": 100,
    "startDelay": "PT5S",
    "period": "PT30S",
    "useEarliestOffset": false,
    "completionTimeout": "PT1200S",
    "lateMessageRejectionPeriod": null,
    "earlyMessageRejectionPeriod": null,
    "stream": "Test",
    "useEarliestSequenceNumber": false
  },
  "context": null,
  "suspended": false
}
```

I hope, someone can spot the error there.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The log created by the ingestion task

```
{
  "0": {
    "index_kafka_Test_4b0ecd3ab842a29_bebmfiod": {
      "movingAverages": {
        "buildSegments": {
          "5m": {
            "processed": 0,
            "unparseable": 1,
            "thrownAway": 0,
            "processedWithError": 0
          },
          "15m": {
            "processed": 0,
            "unparseable": 1,
            "thrownAway": 0,
            "processedWithError": 0
          },
          "1m": {
            "processed": 0,
            "unparseable": 1,
            "thrownAway": 0,
            "processedWithError": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "totals": {
        "buildSegments": {
          "processed": 0,
          "processedWithError": 0,
          "thrownAway": 0,
          "unparseable": 8
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error trace?

Comment: I've seen no error trace, sadly. Only a state of the task, wait a sec!

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I edited the question and appended it by the log, which I read

Comment: Perhaps this would be useful? https://www.confluent.io/connector/druid-kafka-indexing-service/